# Emgu.CV.InRange returns a black image

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I got an image and performing the following function:

```
Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.InRange(Img, new Emgu.CV.ScalarArray(new Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvScalar((byte)0, (byte)0, (byte)0)), new Emgu.CV.ScalarArray(new Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvScalar((byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255)), Img);
```

If i don't perform an explicit cast to byte, nothing changes.

The function returns a black image and I don't get it, because the range 0 to 255 should include all colors. If I comment the function, the image is the correct image, I initialy loaded.

Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. As that Mat object has four channels, the array for upper and lower bound also needs to have four items.

```
Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.InRange(Img, new Emgu.CV.ScalarArray(new Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvScalar((byte)0, (byte)0, (byte)0), (byte)0)), new Emgu.CV.ScalarArray(new Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvScalar((byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255)), Img);
```